# How to prevent rerenders with react-router-dom and react-redux when changing route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I have these routers

```
function Rutas(){
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
     <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/">
       <Home />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/about">
       <About />
      </Route>
     </Switch>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
}
```

This is my Sidebar

```
function Home(){
 return (
   <>
    <NavLink to="/home">Home</NavLink>
    <NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink>
   </>
 )
}
```

And this is the Home component

```
function Home(){
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
 const homeData = useSelector((data) => data.homeData);
 React.useEffect(() => dispatch(getHomeDataAction),[dispatch])

 return (
   <>
    {
     homeData.map((res) => <span>{res.title}</span>)
    }
   </>
 )
}
```

And this is the About component

```
function About(){
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
 const aboutData = useSelector((data) => data.aboutData);
 React.useEffect(() => dispatch(getAboutDataAction),[dispatch])

 return (
   <>
    {
     aboutData.map((res) => <span>{res.title}</span>)
    }
   </>
 )
}
```

On page load for the first time the Home component rendered, that's okay, when i change route to About component it's rendered too and this it's okay, but the problem it's when i change route again to the Home component it's rendered again and it call useEffect and dispatch again, I WANT TO PREVENT TO DISPATCH AGAIN WHEN THE ROUTE CHANGE BECOUSE I HAVE A LOT OF DATA AND IT TAKE A WHILE TO RENDERED AGAIN THE DATA FROM USESELECTOR AND THE UI IT'S SO SLOW.

Please tell me some solution or recommendations.

Thanks ☺

Comment: Writing requirements in CAPTIAL letters won't give you faster or better answers. Instead try to be humble, order your thoughts and take care to work our your details.

Answer (score 0):

You could somehow memorize does `getHomeDataAction` action was dispatched or not.

```
    const loadedData = useSelector((data) => data.homeData.loaded);
    React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!loadedData) {  
      dispatch(getHomeDataAction)
    } 

  },[dispatch, loadedData])
```

All in all calling the `getHomeDataAction` action conditionally could help.
Apart from these changes you should extend your reducer.
After dispatching `getHomeDataAction` action the first time the value of the `loaded` property should be turned to true.

Comment: I did it like you show me, but when i dispatch getHomeDataAction again that take a lot of time to render data again from const aboutData = useSelector((data) => data.aboutData);